# Correct typing for nextElementSibling so .focus() can be used?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, types, element

I am attempting to move focus in my form programatically with `nextElementSibling`, however I am also using Typescript and wanting to type my variables/constants...

I have had success **without** typing, and using the following:

```
myFunct(event) {
  const myEl = event.srcElement;
  const nextElement = myEl.nextElementSibling;

  if (nextElement) {
    nextElement.focus();
  }
}
```

However, when using types on the code I am getting inconsistencies and the following IntelliJ warning:

> Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'Element'

```
myFunct(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  const myEl: Element = event.srcElement;
  const nextElement: Element = myEl.nextElementSibling;

  if (nextElement) {
    nextElement.focus();
  }
}
```

However upon Googling, I find that the type for `nextElementSibling` should actually be `Element`, according to **[Mozilla](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/flipsnap--flipsnap/interfaces/htmlelement.html#nextelementsibling)**

Can anybody help?

**UPDATE:**

It appears that the `KeyboardEvent` on the `event` is actually causing the issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement): Element inherits properties from its parent, Element, and implements those from GlobalEventHandlers and TouchEventHandlers.

Hence, you can change your code to (code tested with [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)):

```js
function myFunct(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  const myEl = <HTMLElement>event.srcElement;
  const nextElement = <HTMLElement>myEl.nextElementSibling;

  if (nextElement) {
    nextElement.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I had forgotten about forcing typing in this way. Would it be overkill to write it such as `const nextElement: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>myEl.nextElementSibling`?

Comment: @physicsboy No, it's an error. You may see it in action on [ typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)